# Command line proccess read linux in java

Tags: java, linux, bash, command-line

I'm trying execute this:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef | grep bash");

    BufferedReader r =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
```

and want see some lines, but it return `Null`.

If I execute just `"ps -ef"` it return all process correct.

Generally I need to send keyword to method, that return work process or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
String[] command =  {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ps -ef | grep bash"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```